# how to add a hero card in the message controller under conversation update dialogue. (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, chatbot

i want to show a hero card message in my chat bot as soon as a user opens the bot. 
Thus it is supposed to be under the conversation update container of the message controller class. 
So how to add a hero card in the Conversation update dialogue of message controller class ?
Language: C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, you have to add your HeroCard constructor in the conversation update portion of the controller.

```
else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
        {
            if (message.MembersAdded.Any(o => o.Id == message.Recipient.Id))
            {
                var reply = message.CreateReply();

                var card = new HeroCard();
                // Make your HeroCard as you wish

                reply.Attachments.Add(card.ToAttachment());

                ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(message.ServiceUrl));

                await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hey Arun! thanks for taking out time to answer my query, what you have shared, in that i just need to add the structure for hero card and it shall work right?